How to handle and replace message from SubProtocolWebSocketHandler in Spring Stomp Web Socket
I am using WebClientSocket library from Arduino and connect with Spring Boot Web Socket.
The issue occur when command send from microcontroller to web server socket.
STOMP command has end of string symbol '\u0000' and spring web socket can't parsed because of this character
:
[SEND ..data..\u0000]
I guess I can intercept and replace income message into spring web server. I've found appropriate class class SubProtocolWebSocketHandler and handleMessage() method.
If my though is right, does somebody give me an worked example - how to intercept input  command  on web [SEND...\u0000] socket STOMP server?
Thanks in advance
